# How to simlify MS SQL server database restore?

Tags: sql, backup-restoration

I have to restore various SQL server databases several times a day (for development purposes). In SSMS interface it takes forever and it is even longer to type RESTORE DATABASE command with all it's paths. Ideally I would like to double-click a BAK file right in Windows Explorer and run something to restore it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeware [One-Click SQL Restore](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/restore/) associates with .bak files and claims to restore in a couple of clicks

Answer (score 1):

We've simply built scripts which take inputs as to the name of the backup file, the type of backup, etc. and use those globally. Another option is to look at a tool like Red Gate's SQL Backup. Backups and restores through a few mouse clicks and it'll even script what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common to write the backup database command, and then put that into a SQL Server job - which can be executed either on demand or on schedule. That works perfectly for many when the restore point is the same each time.

Have you thought about using database snapshots before you do your work? It allows you to rollback to when the snapshot was taken very very quickly indeed.

The only things to be aware of with snapshots are that there is a small performance overhead, and that it's in the Enterprise/developer editions. That'll be generally fine in development, but the edition will let you develop using features that aren't in Standard edition.